# Keycloak / Spring boot failed to turn code into token

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, keycloak

I installed keycloak on a centos 7 server, and I deployed my spring boot project on the same server.

The issue is that after I login, I get

```
[nio-8090-exec-2] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator: failed to turn code into token
May 20 16:17:08 java[858]: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
 java[858]: at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
 java[858]: at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
 java[858]: at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
 java[858]: at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
 java[858]: at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
 java[858]: at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
 java[858]: at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:543) ~[httpclient-4.5.8.jar!/:4.5.8]
+ 52 more
```

**My keycloak config:**

[image: a busy cat]

**application.properties**

```
server.port = 8090
server.servlet.contextPath=/demo
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://mywebsite.com/auth
keycloak.realm=myREALM
keycloak.resource=login
keycloak.credentials.secret=xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx
keycloak.security-constraints[0].authRoles[0]=user
keycloak.security-constraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/test/*
```

**nginx.conf**

```
upstream keycloak {
    ip_hash;
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

upstream demoServer {
    ip_hash;
    server 127.0.0.1:8090;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    #server_name mywebsite.com;
    #return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} 

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    server_name mywebsite.com;

    location /auth/ { 
      proxy_set_header Host $host; 
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; 
      proxy_pass http://keycloak/auth/;

    } 

    location /demo/ { 
      proxy_set_header Host $host; 
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_pass http://demoServer/demo/;
    }
}
```

**The result**

[image: a busy cat]

PS : I am using keycloak 6.0.0 and Spring boot 2.1.4

Comment: This issue yo are facing when you try to connect your application and Keycloak? What if you directly access the Keycloak and try to login its working?

Comment: I get the issue when I try to access my app via keycloak. And, if by direct access you mean that I can connect to /auth, so yes I can.

Comment: Did you tried to check server.log of Keyclaok ? Please have  look and see what its telling,another thing you can try in `redirecturls   ` please provide  `*` in place of URL.

Comment: I checked server.log and I found the following warning that I think it might be behind the issue ```2019-05-15 16:46:19,734 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-1) type=REFRESH_TOKEN_ERROR, realmId=myREALM, clientId=login, userId=null, ipAddress=10.0.0.1, error=invalid_token, grant_type=refresh_token, client_auth_method=client-secret```. Any ideas??

Comment: Also I followed this [tutorial](http://pimwiddershoven.nl/entry/install-keycloak-on-centos-7-with-mysql-backend)

Comment: Is this possible to check your setup,Why you install NGINX and added keycloak behind it?

Comment: I am using keycloak to secure and manage access to my spring boot App. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193475/discussion-between-subodh-joshi-and-aymen-fatnassi).